# How do I add Generic constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I have the following situation in C#:

```
class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    public void do()
    {
    }
}

class SpecificFooImpl : MyGenericClass<Foo>
{
     public void otherStuff()
     {
     }
}
```

Now I want to write a generic method which can return only `MyGenericClass<T>` or specific implementations. I would write something like:

```
var v1 = GetMyClass<MyGenericClass<Foo>>();
var v2 = GetMyClass<MyGenericClass<Bar>>();
var v3 = GetMyClass<SpecificFooImpl>();
```

I could use the following signature but it have no constraints on the type:

```
public T GetMyClass<T>();
//I don't want to write
//var v4 = GetMyClass<AnyOtherTypesWhichNotExtendMyGenericClass>();
```

Is there any elegant mode to solve the problem?

Comment: so add a constraint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a where : clause after the definition, then you can define what should be obeyed.
I've said it must be a class but you can add a base class or interface as a constraint.

```
class MyGenericClass<T> where T : class, IYourCommonInterface
{
    public void do()
    {
    }
}
```

**References**:
See MSDN on constraints: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: How can I write the where clause? I cannot find a way to achieve it!

Comment: Copy what I have, then define an interface or another base class as a constraint

Answer (score 2):

This gets a little tricky, as you can't leave the type constraint open - it has to be concrete.

So what you'd like to do is:

```
public T GetMyClass<T>() where T: MyGenericClass<>
```

However the closest you'd get is to include a second generic type that makes `MyGenericClass` concrete:

```
public T GetMyClass<T,T2>() where T: MyGenericClass<T2>
```

However this makes the caller need to know too much about the implementation, especially where you're using `SpecificFooImpl`.

Instead, consider using an interface to remove your inner generic type:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    void Stuff();
}

class MyGenericClass<T> : MyInterface
{
    public void Stuff()
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can have:

```
public T GetMyClass<T>() where T : MyInterface
```

Comment: All of the desired usages will work (eg `var v3 = GetMyClass<SpecificFooImpl>();`) since they all derive from `MyGenericClass<T>` which now implements `MyInterface`.